# PHP Contact Form return 500 Internal Error

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, phpmailer

I have a contact form

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post" class="needs-validation" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div id="contactForm" class="form-row col-12 justify-content-left">
        <div class="row col-12 justify-content-center">
            <div id="contactFirst" class="col-3">
                <label for="firstName">First</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" required="required">
                <div class="valid-feedback">
                    Looks good!
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="contactLast" class="col-3">
                <label id="last" for="lastName">Last</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required="required">
                <div class="valid-feedback">
                    Looks good!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row col-12 justify-content-center">
            <div id="formEmail" class="col-3">
                <label for="inputEmail">
                Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required">
            </div>
            <div id="contactSelect" class="col-3">
                <label id="desiredServices" for="selectService">
                Desired Service</label>
                <select class="custom-select selectService" required="required">
                    <option value="">Select One</option>
                    <option value="1">Web Development</option>
                    <option value="2">Corporate Wellness</option>
                    <option value="3">Web Marketing</option>
                </select>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Please select your desired service!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row col-12 justify-content-center">
            <div id="contactMessage" class="form-group row col-6">
                <label for="message">Message</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contactButton" class="text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

After submiting it, I kept getting

[image]

closer look

[image]

## contact

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$HOST       = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$PORT       = 587;
$USERNAME   = 'noreply.b@gmail.com';
$PASSWORD   = '******';
$FROM_EMAIL = $USERNAME;
$FROM_NAME  = 'T m';
$TO_EMAIL   = 'T.m.44@gmail.com';
$TO_NAME    = 'T m';
$SITE_URL   = 'https://Tm.com/';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $lastName  = $_POST['lastName'];
    $email     = $_POST['email'];
    $message   = $_POST['message'];
};

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_OFF;

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host       = $HOST;
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->Username   = $USERNAME;
    $mail->Password   = $PASSWORD;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port       = $PORT;

    $mail->setFrom($FROM_EMAIL, $FROM_NAME);
    $mail->addAddress($TO_EMAIL, $TO_NAME);

    $mail->isHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject = "Web enquiry";
    $mail->Body    = "<strong>Name:</strong><br/> <br/>".$_POST['firstName'] . ' ' . $_POST['lastName'] . '<br/><br/> <strong>Email:</strong> <br/><br/>' . $email . '<br/> <br/><strong>Message:</strong> <br/> <br/>' . $_POST['message'] . '<br/><br/> -- <br/><br/>This e-mail was sent from a contact form on ' . $SITE_URL;
    $mail->AltBody = "From: non-HTML mail".$_POST['message'];

        if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
        };
?>
```

I am hosting in Ubuntu VM using **Apache**.

**What should I check to debug this further ?**

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail.

Comment: Apache or PhP log ?

Comment: This may not be related, but I strongly urge you to use a real mail gateway instead of Gmail. It's not designed for programmatic use.

Comment: It depends how your web server is configured. Start by reading the Apache error log and go from there. If you've got other error logs configured, read them too.